# How can i add a value to a register inside of a for loop in Verilog?

Tags: for-loop, verilog, counter

I am currently trying to make a simple up counter inside of Verilog where the counter increases by 1 whenever i come across a '1' in an 8-bit stream. So for example with the 8-bit in put 8'b11001100, the output register would be 4'b0100.
I created a for loop to pass through the 8-bit stream to see whenever i come across a '1' but whenever i try to add 1 to my register i get very odd assigning errors i have never seen before. Any help would be appreciated! Here is my source.

```
module stream_counter(stream);

input[7:0] stream;
output[3:0] stream_counter;

reg[3:0] stream_counter;
genvar index;
genvar counter;

always @ (stream)
counter = 0;

for(index = 0; index < 8; index = index +1) begin
    if(stream[index]) begin
        counter = counter + 1;
    end
end 
end 

assign stream_counter = counter;
endmodule
```

The errors i am getting when compiling are:

** Error: (vlog-13069) stream_counter.v(15): near "=": syntax error, unexpected '='.

** Error: stream_counter.v(15): (vlog-13205) Syntax error found in the scope following 'counter'. Is there a missing '::'?

Comment: You have several misconceptions in the code. So, please read about  modules, always blocks, sensitivity lists, and  generate blocks.

Answer (score -1):

At first glance you're missing a begin after the first always block declaration.
And I would use an asterisk to let the tool manage the sensitivity list.
For example:

```
always @ (*) begin
...
```

Comment: there are numerous errors in the original post. this answer does not help anything, just adds more confsion